# Swift 3 Uploading data to a server with Alamofire

Tags: swift, xcode, web-services, alamofire

I'm currently using alamofire to request data from  a web service.Everything works great but I have a doubt about how to upload data to my server with the **method get**.

Example of web service --> http://www.google.com/id=2&name=trump&message=fakenews

I tried to use the traditional alamofire.request("weberservice") but It didn't work.

How do I send this information using alamofire?

Comment: Can you show your code? On a side note, GET is used to retrieve data, POST is what you should be using to send to your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is make a `POST` request. This sends data to the server.

What you will do is use the `request` method, but add an additional argument for the HTTP method:

```
Alamofire.request("<YOUR-URL>", method: .post)
```

The Alamofire docs [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#parameter-encoding) talk about passing the data to the server when you make the `POST` request. You basically add a 3rd argument with the dictionary:

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["foo": "bar"]

// All three of these calls are equivalent
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: parameters)

// https://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar
```

*From the Alamofire docs*

Comment: but, for example when i declare the parameters and i call them to the .request, are they sended according to the name of the parameters?

Comment: Just a las question, how do i get the result from my web service after the insert, the result it is not in JSON, it is a simple echo "insert successful", how to I obtain that response, i tried with a simple .response but it didn't work

Comment: @xx_name I am not familiar enough with the Alamofire API to know how to get the response from a `POST` request if `response` is not working.

Comment: I found out a why to know if the post was successful, it is the downloadprogress method -> thank you very much :)